# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to connect an app to a remote Worklight Server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

How do I connect a Worklight App to a remote WL Server? To be more precise, what all config changes and where should I make them, so that the WL App is at-least available in the WL Console (later I can upload all .wlapp files).

I was using WL version 5 earlier, so I do have some rough knowledge of how they work. But in WL version 6.1, I don't have any clues.

I am following the information center topic "Changing the Worklight Server associated with a project", but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Worklight 6.1 the `Build and Deploy` action is now `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`.

Similarly, and expended upon the `remote deploy` action is now
`Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target`

See the following documentation topic: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_building_and_deploying_build_settings_deploy_target.html

Comment: I have tried using "Run As > Build Settings and Deploy Target". But there 2 sections: 1. Worklight server to test applications >> Add Server and 2. Check box - Build the application to work with a  different Worklight Server. Which one to choose from and how to test if the selected option is working.

Comment: Thanks Idan! Below note is from the link only. Does it mean that using WL Studio Dev Edition, I can't deploy to a remote server? If that is the case, do I need to used "Worklight Server to test applications" instead? - "Note: Both Worklight Studio Consumer Edition and Worklight Studio Enterprise Edition provide the capability to deploy to the internal Worklight Development Server, and, using this area of the dialog, to a remote server. The Worklight Studio Developer Edition is provided for evaluation purposes, and you can deploy only to the internal Worklight Development Server."

Comment: You cannot deploy directly to a remote server, but you can set up the details in the dialog and run the build. The produced .wlapp and native folders will point to the remote server. You the take the .wlapp and manually deploy it in the remote server via its worklight console.

Comment: I understand your point. But what I am trying to ask is - suppose I am selecting "**Build the application to work with a different server**" and am **using WL Studio Developer Edition**. Then, as per the "Note" above which says "....The Worklight Studio Developer Edition is provided for evaluation purposes, and you can deploy only to the internal Worklight Development Server." - **I can't deploy to remote server. Since I am using a Developer Edition of WL Studio** and NOT Worklight Studio Consumer Edition and Worklight Studio Enterprise Edition. Right?

Comment: Although, **I might be able to deploy to remote server** when using "**Worklight Server to test applications**" and providing all the server details.

Comment: Technically speaking you probably can... but then again you SHOULD NOT mix the Developer Edition with your Production environments. Keep development for development.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46768/discussion-between-user2072344-and-idan-adar)

Comment: Based on the chat, your question is now answered. Please mark as answered. Thanks!